# How tom properly display many table records in views

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here have three tables with association and relationship as follows

**Categor** table is the main table

**Product** table belongs to categor table where its product_id references categor(id)

**Sale** table belongs to Product table where its sale_id references product(id)

Here am am trying to get records based on their refrences where:

just consider this three tables as Categor as the main table, product as sub table and sales as sub table under product

1.) categor table will loop and display all the records in it.

2.) product table should loop and display its record based on categor_id where it matches id of the categor table.

3)  sale table should loop and display its record based on product_id where it matches id of the product.

just consider this three tables as Post, comment and reply

```
def index


    #@categors = Categor.where(:id => '1')
    @categors = Categor.all 
    @prods = Product.where(:categor_id => '1')
    @sals = Sale.where(:product_id => '1')

end
```

At this point, I can successfully display all the records but can not get it be aligned properly.

Categor is the main table.
Products info should be under Categor.
sales info should be under products.

Just view it as post, comment and reply respectively.

```
<p id="notice"><%= notice %></p>
  <div>
    <% @categors.each do |categor| %>

        Categorid: <%= categor.id %>
        Category Name: <%= categor.cat_name %>
        Ctaegory Label<%= categor.car_label %>
              </div>
    <% end %><br>



 <% @prods.each do |pr| %>

       Product id: <%= pr.id %>
        Product Name: <%= pr.prod_name %>
    <% end %>
<br>



 <% @sals.each do |s| %>
        sales id: <%= s.id %>
        sales Name: <%= s.sales_name %>
    <% end %>
<br>





<br>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand what you are trying to accomplish here, but I'm going to assume you are trying to display all categories, and all products in each category and all sales for each product.

There are several different ways that you could structure this, like for example tree views or nested tables, etc, and you should take in consideration how useable the page will be once you have a lot of categories/products/sales, but for the sake of simplicity let's structure them as nested lists:

```
<ul>
<% @categors.each do |categor| %>

  <li><%= categor.cat_name %>

    <ul>
    <% categor.products.each do |pr| %>

      <li><%= pr.prod_name %>

        <ul>
        <% pr.sales.each do |s| %>

          <li><%= s.sales_name %></li>

        <% end %>
        </ul>

      </li>

    <% end %>
    </ul>

  </li>

<% end %>
</ul>
```

Now you didn't show us how your models are setup so i don't know if the relationships between them are properly set but I'm assuming yes.

Comment: Thank you sir Julien. Your solution  works perfectly. before I mark and upvote your amazing solution. I have a question. From your answer, it seems that this nested approach will have a performance issue with more content on the page. please how do facebook handle their post, comments and reply  with load more content button on the same page. what approach do youtube used to display video post, comments, reply on the same page. I need to be guided. thanks

Comment: as for model categor model has this   class Categor < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :products
  has_many :sales, :through => :products
end

Comment: at products model I have belong_to : categor      and at  sales model i have belong_to: product

Comment: Facebook, Youtube, and etc load the data through AJAX requests, you can learn more about it [here](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/ajax_intro.asp)

Comment: Thanks alot. you have made my day easier